# URI tutorial/documentation

Tags: c#, wcf, uri

I am working on a WCF service that needs to receive parameters through a WebGet call. In order to do this, I realize I'm going to have to pass them through the URI template. In attempting to do this it became apparent that I lack a basic knowledge of URI formats.

I have tried to no avail to find a good tutorial or any kind of basic documentation about constructing URI's.

For example, what does the ? mean and what are some other really fundamental URI elements?

Comment: The Wikipedia article has a very good discussion. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) and [Uri RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) should be good starting points.

Sample from [UriBuilder.Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.query.aspx)

```
UriBuilder baseUri = new UriBuilder(
    "http://www.contoso.com/default.aspx?Param1=7890");
string queryToAppend = "param2=1234";

if (baseUri.Query != null && baseUri.Query.Length > 1)
    baseUri.Query = baseUri.Query.Substring(1) + "&" + queryToAppend; 
else
    baseUri.Query = queryToAppend;
```

Comment: Thanks, the URIbuilder documentation had everything I was looking for.